# in Ruby on Rails, what is the kENSURE and kEND in error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby on Rails, I sometimes get an error on the page as:

> compile error
>   /Users/jian/ror/shov2/app/views/stories/index.html.erb:13:
>   syntax error, unexpected **kENSURE**,
>   expecting ')'
>   /Users/jian/ror/shov2/app/views/stories/index.html.erb:15:
>   syntax error, unexpected **kEND**,
>   expecting ')'

the kEND, i can guess that it is End... so it means End of file but unexpected, there should be a ')'.

how about the kENSURE ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The kEND constant refers to the token "end", as in what you end every code block with. An ensure block is the equivalent of a finally block in other languages.

```
begin
  1/0
rescue ZeroDivisionError
  puts "OH SHI-"
ensure # <- THIS THING
  1/1
  puts "Whew, we're safe"
end
```

That's what kENSURE refers to.

It sounds like you forgot to put the closing paren at the end of either a method call or a method parameter list.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I had `<%= end %>` instead of `<% end %>`. Thanks John!

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure you have a `do` after any clauses that are expecting blocks.

Doing something like

```
<%= form_tag "action" %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Will cause this same error

Answer (score 1):

Check that the delimiters (e.g. `<%` `%>` etc.) in your ERB templates match.

Answer (score 0):

keyword `ensure` from exception handling.